# Dynatree slow when rendering large trees

Tags: performance, tree, dynatree

I'm looking for hints on how to render faster large trees with Dynatree

I just gave a try to the Dynatree jquery plugin.

I try to render a pretty large tree : Root has exactly 7592 child nodes, something like 10 levels deep from root

On my PC with Firefox browser, Firebug tells me that I get :

- page content loaded after 2.68s (this depends on network speed, 356
  KB to be loaded)
- DOMcontentloaded at 3s
- then 'load' arrives at 9s

So it takes about 6s to render the tree.

Code to build the tree is made of HTML, with ul, li and "a href" tags
The whole tree is created on request at server side, it doesnt take more than 500ms with classic ASP and SQL server to generate HTML for the page

is there a way to improve speed ?
using JSON ?
using lasy mode ? how can i set this mode on non-ajax trees ?

Best regards

Fred

Answer (score 0):

That sounds slower than I would expect.

I would recommend to build the data on the server and send as JSON.
If that is still too slow, only send the first or first and second levels and mark them 'lazy', so they will be loaded on demand.
You'll find a sample here:
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-lazy.html

There is also a benchmark page, that you may use as a reference: http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/test-bench.html

Comment: Hi & thank you ... pfiouu this interface is not easy to use... nothing intuitive